# How does writing a new scanner in a while loop stop an otherwise infinite loop?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I am trying to stop an error from happening if the user inputs a number other than 1,2,3, so I created a while loop to make the program keep asking the user for a new number if their input is outside 1,2,3. 
Before I didn't have the

```
 Scanner user1 = new Scanner(System.in);
 input = user1.nextInt();
```

lines, and the while loop kept running infinitely. But now the code does what I want, it stops and evaluates the new user input for as many times as the input is wrong (I've entered 3,6,7 wrong values before a correct one and it works every time).

My question is, how does the scanner stop the infinite loop? Does the Scanner impletmentation cause the computer to wait for a user input before it continues, and so because of this it goes back to evaluate it continuously, instead of infinitely printing out "I'm sorry that's not a valid input..." ? I just want to be sure I know WHY it's stopping.

```
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Hello, what would you like to do?" + "\n" + "1. Search"  + "\n" + "2. Add new instructor" + "\n" + "3. Remove Intsructor");
int input = user.nextInt(); 
boolean valid = false;
while(valid == false)
{
    if(input<3 && input>=1)
    {

        valid = true; 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("I'm sorry, that's not a valid input, please enter 1, 2, or 3."); 
        Scanner user1 = new Scanner(System.in); 
        input = user1.nextInt(); 
    }
```

Comment: Basically nextInt() will read an int from the underlying stream, which is System.in. The program stops waiting for your input.

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

It stops the loop by waiting. `nextInt()` is a blocking method, meaning when you call it, the thread that called it will wait until that method either returns a value, or the reason for the block has finished.

When you call nextInt(), your thread haults, and waits until something comes through `System.in`. Once something comes in, the method returns the value.

If you put `scanner.nextInt()` inside of of your loop, then each loop iteration will wait for user input

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean valid = true;

while(valid) {
    switch(scanner.nextInt()) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            valid = false; //if nextInt() is 1 or 2
            break;

        default: //anything else

            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

- Your loop stops only when `valid` is set to `true`
- `valid` is set to `true` only when `input` is 1 or 2
- If `input` is outside the valid range, `valid` does not change
- If `input` is outside the range upon the first entry into the loop, the only way to stop the loop is to change the value of `input`.

Without the two lines that you added, i.e. without

```
Scanner user1 = new Scanner(System.in);
input = user1.nextInt();
```

the loop does not change `input`. Therefore, if the loop is not exited right away, it stays infinite.

Note that you do not need to create a new scanner - you can read from the one that you created before the loop, i.e.

```
input = user.nextInt();
```

Also note that calling `nextInt()` without calling `hasNextInt()` may produce an exception.